# How to securely register users on App Engine using multiple OAUTH providers?

Tags: android, facebook, google-app-engine, oauth, authorization

I would like to discuss a common scenario: An app wants to authorize users using multiple OAUTH providers, such as Facebook, Google+ or Twitter.

Essentially this question has been asked two years ago here [Mobile API Authentication Using Existing Web App with Multiple OAuth Providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928082/mobile-api-authentication-using-existing-web-app-with-multiple-oauth-providers) and stays unanswered, so I will elaborate a bit further. (I will use Facebook as an example for the OAUTH2 provider, so this does not become too generic.)

Essentially, user registration works like this: OAUTH/OAUTH2 providers typically provide a workflow where a (mostly short-lived) token is obtained from a provider either via the AccountManager on the mobile device or a login dialog such as the "Login with Facebook" button. The token is then shipped to App Engine by calling a REST endpoint (either in the body or as an additional header, never in the URL).

The provider's AppId and AppSecret (here: Facebook) are store on App Engine and App Engine adds these to the token, then ships it back to Facebook in exchange for a (long-lived) token.

At this point both, client app and App Engine app have certainty that the user has been previously authenticated by Facebook. Also, if Endpoints Authentication is used to authenticate the call, App Engine probably has the Google credentials of the user and/or the ClientId of the app, and Google guarantees that the request has been made from the correct client app.

At this point, we can try to find the user in our datastore and let registration fail (or silently sign in the user) if it already exists, or otherwise create a record.

Until here I am pretty sure I'm on the right track. Now comes the problem:

Let's look at the datastore for this. Let's assume we have two entities:

1. User entity, where each user in our own system is registered under a unique user id.
2. Account entity, where each account is registered and where a userId field points to the User entity.

In relational database terms, we would say we have a 1:n relationship between User and Account.

For each User in our system, we keep a User record. In above example, we may have two accounts: Facebook and Google, which both point to the user and where the unique Facebook or Google id/email is used as account identifier.

Technically it would now be possible that the app uses the Facebook or Google account on subsequent requests. But we would have to store and look up the 3rd-party token on each request because we cannot decrypt it ourselves. We could ask the provider to do this, but that wouldn't make much sense either. Plus we would have to translate the provider's Account id to our own User id on each request.

To solve this problem I would most probably either create our own token or set up our own OAUTH provider which creates a token signed by our own system, and where the unique User id is used as identifier, and only use that token during subsequent requests.

- Is this a good approach? Is anybody using a different better workflow? Does anybody see security flaws with this design?

Essentially it works around Google's endpoints system, but Google can only authenticate against their own systems, so if we want to offer sign-in using further providers, we will need to work around this,  except if anybody knows a workflow where we can keep both, but then we have the problem that we can/should only add a single token in the "Authorization" header and REST principles discourage us to use custom headers to ship more tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your app authenticates a user, store an object in a session which contains an oauth provider that has been used to access the app and, optionally, a token to be used for subsequent requests.

Now you can check for this object in every call to the server. If the object is not present - a user is not authenticated, redirect to the login page. If an object is present, take a token and use it.

I use a similar approach for multiple authentication options, not only oauth. Except I don't need to store a token after a user is authenticated - I have no use for it within the app.

Comment: I agree, wrapping the oauth provider info plus my own token into a session is very smart. This allows for sending multiple identity pieces back and forth. I assume you encrypt the session with a server-side key that only the server knows, because otherwise the oauth provider and my own user id/token could be separated by a hacker and reassembled, and if I don't do cross-checks (which would require datastore reads) the wrong FB token could be matched with the wrong user id and my server may accept it. Do I see this correctly?

Comment: I've been reading a bit and decided to use JWT. If I place the different identity pieces as claims, the signature will ensure integrity of all claims. @AndreiVolgin, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.